# Filter functionality in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am building an apartment renting app in React, with very limited Javascript and programmatic knowledge (using this app to learn while i go). I've stumbled upon a big roadblock trying to build the filter functionality.

Here is the code for the FilterContainer.js container component

```
const FilterContainer = React.createClass({
render () {
    return (
        <section id="filterContainer" className="container">
            <Filter
                name={'Kvart'}
                filterList={['Šubićevac', 'Meterize', 'Baldekin', 'Vidici', 'Rokići', 'Grad']} />
            <Filter
                name={'Cijena'}
                filterList={['< 600kn', '600kn - 700kn', '700kn - 800kn', '800kn - 900kn', '> 900kn']} />
            <Filter
                name={'Broj osoba'}
                filterList={['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']} />
            <Filter
                name={'Kvadratura'}
                filterList={['< 40m', '40m - 50m', '50m - 60m', '60m - 70m', '70m - 80m', '> 80m']} />
        </section>
    )
}});
```

This is the Filter.js component

```
var Filter = React.createClass({
getDefaultProps() {
    return {
        filterList: [],
        name: ''
    };
},
render() {
    var handleClick = function(i, props) {
        console.log('You clicked: ' + props.filterList[i].listValue[i]);
    }
    return (
        <div className="filterCloud quarter-section">
            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            <ul>
                {this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue, i, props) {
                    return <li onClick={handleClick.bind(this, i, props)} key={i}>{listValue}</li>;
                }, this)} {/* this at the end to fix the scope issue from global to local */}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}});
```

This is how the Filter looks on the website atm

[image: This is how the Filters look on the website atm]

The error I am getting is "Filter.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" whenever i click on one of the filter items, I want to be able to save the name of the filter item as data which I will use to filter the apartments.

So the simple issue is the undefined error. The more complex issue i have is the fact that I have no idea how to build the filter functionality in my app, so if any of you guys could point me in the right direction it would help me alot.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter to the [map function in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the full array that is being mapped over.

In this case, it is the `filterList`, not `this.props`.

So in you click handler, you don't need to traverse `props`:

```
var handleClick = function(i, props) {
    console.log('You clicked: ' + props[i].listValue[i]);
}
```

It would be easier to see if you did some renaming:

```
render() {
    var handleClick = function(i, filterList) {
        console.log('You clicked: ' + filterList[i].listValue[i]);
    }
    return (
        <div className="filterCloud quarter-section">
            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            <ul>
                {this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue, i, filterList) {
                    return <li onClick={handleClick.bind(this, i, filterList)} key={i}>{listValue}</li>;
                }, this)} {/* this at the end to fix the scope issue from global to local */}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}});
```